# Google App Engine - inline/iframe log-in

Tags: google-app-engine, iframe

Is there a way to configure Google App Engine so that the log-in page appears either inline or in an iframe, instead of [requiring a link](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/loginurls.html).

I would like it to be as simple as

```
<iframe src="{{ login_url }}">
    <!-- no iframes -->
    <a href="{{login_url}}">Log in</a>
</iframe>
```

However that seems to be an undocumented way to go about logging in users, and I'm not sure if that's the way to go about this.

I'd be grateful for any thoughts

Thank you for reading.

Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a good idea.  By showing a google login form on *your domain* how do your users know it is legitimate?  By redirecting your users to a page on *Google's domain* it reduces the amount of confusion.

Also, you might want to review the Terms before doing this.  I would not be surprised if Google specifically mentions not doing this somewhere.  It's like teaching your users to give up there Google login details whenever prompted.

There have been several posts in the groups discussing this as well;  Nick, and many other users, [responded](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/f3068e7729a60572) to this question with similar comments.

Comment: Thanks for the response; this helps explain why Google hadn't documented this possibility, and I appreciate the concern. However, this concern doesn't seem applicable where GAE is being used on a Google Apps domain e.g. `xyz.com`, and the login is being authenticated against only users accounts of that domain &mdash; or is it?

Comment: If you are authenticating against a Google Apps domain, it will still redirect the users to a login page at a google.com address (something like: https://www.google.com/a/appsdomain.com/ServiceLogin) and prompt them to login with their Google Apps credentials.  So I think it is still valid.  Another option is to redirect your users to the login url automatically.

Comment: I think that the security concern is a reasonable concession for the given usability concern over a pop-up login link.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried doing what you suggest here, except that I don't have the hyperlink inside of the iFrame. I want Google's authentication page to appear in the iFrame over my page rather than redirecting to the authentication page and then back to my page. I also append a query string to the login_url, and my main request then returns a simple "Welcome" message rather than my app's main page.

It works beautifully in the sandbox, but it doesn't work when deployed to GAE. The page returned by Google's login_url refuses to be displayed in an iFrame. The console message is "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options." I've thought about possible workarounds, but Google obviously doesn't want the login page displayed this way. I'm disappointed, because my app uses HttpRequests heavily, so the main page never refreshes otherwise, but I'm still very happy with GAE.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're answering a very old question, though.